# Specify gcc -pg option for catkin?

Tags: navigation, catkin, gcc, amcl, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am working on a project to do some performance profiling on amcl. To do this, I want to use gprof. To use gprof, I need to compile amcl with the -pg option for gcc. How can I do this in the catkin environment? Is this the right approach?

Bonus question: I don't really want to profile all of the navigation package, only amcl. How can I break amcl out of the navigation package so that I am only profiling amcl?

thanks in advance!

dw

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262170/specify-gcc--pg-option-for-catkin?/) by [deedub](https://answers.ros.org/users/28302/deedub/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-05-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The preferred approach is to modify the package's `CMakeLists.txt` to change the compile options:

> set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "-pg")

This will modify the compile options for the whole package, but won't bleed into other packages accidentally due to cmake `include`.

There's also ways to modify compile options per target (so just for one library or executable), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995019/what-is-the-modern-method-for-setting-general-compile-flags-in-cmake

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2017-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [deedub](https://answers.ros.org/users/28302/deedub/) on 2017-05-24**:
Thanks very much for your answer. Just to clarify, this is preferable specifically because it won't bleed into other packages accidentally?

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2017-05-25**:
Correct. catkin_make will actually magically combine all your package cmakes into one. catkin_make_isolated or the very awesome [catkin-tools](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html) will properly isolate packages, making `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)` slightly more tenable.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can simply add it to the `CMakeLists.txt`file.

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -pg")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pg")
```

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2017-05-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [deedub](https://answers.ros.org/users/28302/deedub/) on 2017-05-24**:
I used this snippet on the amcl/CMakeLists.txt file and it worked perfectly. Thanks!